# Add-Type: Cannot add type. The assembly 'System.IO.Compression.FileSystem' could not be found

Tags: .net, powershell

I am using simple PowerShell script in TeamCity Builds.

It requires `System.IO.Compression.FileSystem` and the agent has .NET 4.5.2 installed. Below are the .NET frameworks installed

```
PSChildName         Version             Release             Product            
-----------         -------             -------             -------            
v2.0.50727          2.0.50727.5420                                             
v3.0                3.0.30729.5420                                             
Windows Communic... 3.0.4506.5420                                              
Windows Presenta... 3.0.6920.5011                                              
v3.5                3.5.30729.5420                                             
Client              4.5.51209           379893              4.5.2              
Full                4.5.51209           379893              4.5.2              
Client              4.0.0.0
```

The PowerShell script has following line

```
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.IO.Compression.FileSystem");
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.IO.Compression.FileSystem
```

On the second line, the execution fails with error

```
Add-Type : Cannot add type. The assembly 'System.IO.Compression.FileSystem' could not be found.
At C:\BuildAgent\someFile.ps1:104 char:13
+     Add-Type <<<<  -AssemblyName System.IO.Compression.FileSystem
+ CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (System.IO.Compression.FileSystem:String) [Add-Type], Exception
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : ASSEMBLY_NOT_FOUND,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.AddTypeCommand
```

Strange, but I expected that with `.NET 4.5.2`, PowerShell should be able to load assembly from `GAC`

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: What PowerShell version are you using? And, more importantly, what .NET version does that PowerShell use? Maybe you'll need to force it to use .NET 4 to load this library successfully.

Comment: I am overriding powershell.exe.config with .NET version `v4.0.30319`. It shows GAC=true for `System.IO.Compression.FileSystem` but not able to load the same assembly

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try to load particular DLL instead:

```
Add-Type -Path C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.IO.Compression.FileSystem\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.IO.Compression.FileSystem.dll
```

Comment: fantastic! Can you help over here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39801315/how-to-chain-commands-at-a-special-powershell-4-command-prompt

Answer (score 1):

`LoadWithPartialName()` is obsolete'd, so avoid it when you can; however since `LoadWithPartialName()` is already working in your context, you could also use the Location property from the object that is returned to load the DLL.

```
if($PSVersionTable.PSVersion -lt '5.0'){
   Add-Type -Path ([Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.IO.Compression.FileSystem")).Location;
}else{
   Add-Type -AssemblyName System.IO.Compression.FileSystem
}
```

Comment: LoadWithPartialName is deprecated and you should not use it as you will struggle with it later

Comment: @JrBriones also there's this https://stackoverflow.com/a/6131116/4496560

Comment: @JrBriones, it's a legacy version of PowerShell, otherwise use `Add-Type -As System.IO.Compression.FileSystem`

Comment: @JrBriones, updated to avoid when possible

Answer (score 0):

I had the exactly same error when running PowerShell script. I guess it was some collision of installed .Net version vs. PowerShell version. In my case helped me just to update PowerShell version to the newest one. Can be found here:

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40855

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this instead (and remove the last portion)
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.IO.Compression