# Unable to compress a file with Powershell 2.0

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

Q1. I tried few compressed method but none of it work on my machine. I just can use external zip tool 7z.exe to compressed the file but I dont have the privilege to install the 7z.exe file in serverA nor update the powershell to v5. *currently using powershell v2* 
Tried as below but none of it working. So, any other method can intro me for compressed file?

- Add-Type -assembly "system.io.compression.filesystem"
- Compress-Archive
- Add-Type -Path C:\Reference\Draftdoc.docx
- C:\Reference\Images\diagram2.vsd -CompressionLevel Optimal
  -DestinationPath C:\Archives\Draft.Zip

Q2. Below are the query I'm using 7z.exe tools (this serverB does come with 7z.exe) but I encountered error. I want to compress any file with today's date.

```
$timestamp = (Get-Date).ToString('yyyy-MM')
$source = "D:\csv\*.csv", "D:\csv2\*.csv"
$target = "D:\CSV2_$timestamp.zip"
$7zip = "D:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe"

#Compressed file
if (-not (test-path $7zip)) {throw '$7zip needed'} 
set-alias sz $7zip  

sz a -mx=9 $target $source
{
    Get-ChildItem $source | Where{$_.LastWriteTime -gt (Get-Date).AddDays(-1)}
}
```

Note: Both server I also need compressed file but ServerA doesnt come 7z, but Server B does come with 7z.exe

Comment: Step 1 is to upgrade to a version of PowerShell that is not deprecated. PS 2.0 is old, insecure, and unsupported. You should use 5.0 at least, preferably newer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to use the much older [`Shell.Application` COM Object method](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/daiken/2007/02/12/compress-files-with-windows-powershell-then-package-a-windows-vista-sidebar-gadget/).

```
function Extract-Zip
{
    param([string]$zipfilename, [string] $destination)

    if(test-path($zipfilename))
    {   
        $shellApplication = new-object -com shell.application
        $zipPackage = $shellApplication.NameSpace($zipfilename)
        $destinationFolder = $shellApplication.NameSpace($destination)
        $destinationFolder.CopyHere($zipPackage.Items())
    }
}
```

Note that I think this only works on Windows Vista or Server 2008 or later. If you're using Server 2003 -- and you should not be -- then you'll have to use third party software, as far as I'm aware.

It should go without saying, but you desperately need to update your servers. I'm not saying you need to install the most recent PowerShell. I'm saying that you're obviously using Server 2008 R2 or earlier, and this is 2019.

Comment: I'm using Window Server 2008 and Powershell v2 :'D is this method going to work for Window Server 2016. I will have an upgrade to WS2016 in next year before the upgrade i gonna automated the compression of file first.

Comment: @user3542587 Yes, it should work with 2016 as well, too. This uses the zip component that Windows Explorer uses, so any version of Windows that has native ZIP support should work. I can't remember if that existed in XP/2k3, but I know it was there in Vista/2k8. You should eventually update your code to use the native `Expand-Archive`, however, because COM objects can be a little flaky in PowerShell. They don't use .Net objects, so they don't work as well as native .Net classes.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
Add-Type -Assembly "System.IO.Compression.FileSystem"
[System.IO.Compression.ZipFile]::CreateFromDirectory($sourcePath, $destinationZip)
```

See [Add-Type: Cannot add type. The assembly 'System.IO.Compression.FileSystem' could not be found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36738392/add-type-cannot-add-type-the-assembly-system-io-compression-filesystem-could/36744763) for alternative ways to load the required assembly

Comment: I don't believe that this was supported on PowerShell 2 (which was shipped with Windows 7 and the corresponding server edition - 2008R2, IIRC). With PowerShell 2, the querent's only option may be to use an external compression program like 7Zip. If he doesn't have sufficient rights to install it on the server, he may need to contact his system administrator for further assistance.

Comment: @mhu Add-Type : Cannot add type. The assembly 'system.io.compression.filesystem' could not be found. I mentioned on above post.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin thanks for your clarification. i thought this just happened to me which unable to use different syntax of compression. btw, any idea how to deal with Q2?

Comment: Without knowing what error you're encountering, there's no way to even begin to address that art of the question.

Answer (score 0):

According to your second question, where 7z is installed in ServerB, this function archive the files you want, this code do not depend on the powershell version you have.

```
function Compress-Items ($ItemsPaths, $dest) {
    $Path = "D:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe"
    $argList = "a -tzip -y `"$dest`""
    foreach ($item in $ItemsPaths) {
        $argList += " `"$item`""
    }

    Start-Process -FilePath $Path -ArgumentList $argList
}

$source = (get-childitem -Path "D:\csv", "D:\csv2" -Include "*.csv" -Recurse).FullName
Compress-Items -ItemsPaths $source -dest $destination
```

**Note**

I modified your `$source` because this is the right way to get all the csv files you want.